# How to disable flymake for files edited over network with TRAMP?

Tags: tramp

My flymake configuration

```
;; flymake
(require 'flymake-cursor)  ;; Hoover over error to show help message

;; use pyflakes for Python
(when (load "flymake" t)
  (defun flymake-pyflakes-init ()
    (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                       'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
           (local-file (file-relative-name
                        temp-file
                        (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
      (list "pyflakes" (list local-file))))

  (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
               '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pyflakes-init)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook)

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)
```

It works fine locally but breaks when I try to edit files remotely. I have no intention of fixing that, I'm almost not using it, how can I disable it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
# -*- eval:(flymake-mode-off) -*-
```

I use this as a file local variable for remote files.